# How to pass PYTHONPATH to external tools in Pydev/Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I'd like to set up some "External tool" for Eclipse. This tool is meant to be run for a particular project and also requires PYTHONPATH to be initialized.

Is there a way to pass the PYTHONPATH to the tool execution, just as the Python interpreter configured in Pydev would usually do?

EDIT: My intend is to set the PYTHONPATH depending on the current active Pydev project - this is only known to the project. So it's not a hardcoded solution, I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyDev does that on its integrations (i.e.: PyLint), but currently does not provide a variable which you can use to resolve on external tools, so, please create a feature request for that.

An option in the current structure without the variable would be using the scripting layer to execute an external tool (http://pydev.org/manual_articles_scripting.html). From the scripting layer it should be possible to get the PYTHONPATH from the editor.

i.e.: something like:

```
nature = editor.getPythonNature()
if nature:   
    nature.getPythonPathNature().getCompleteProjectPythonPath(nature.getProjectInterpreter(),
                            nature.getRelatedInterpreterManager())
```

Comment: Thanks. Great work btw! Just to make sure I havent missed something: Is there another way to run an IPython HTML Notebook with the PYTHONPATH of the current project?

Comment: Well, I don't think you actually need an external tool to run python code from PyDev... can't you just do a regular Python run in this case? (not sure exactly what you want to accomplish, so, this may or may not be an option there -- I was under the impression that you wanted to do a builder).

Comment: I don't actually want to run particular Python code, but just open an IPython HTML Notebook with all module paths loaded :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your case is not covered by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249995/how-to-persist-pythonpath-setting-of-an-eclipse-pydev-project) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324502/most-efficient-way-of-setting-up-a-project-pydev-pythonpath-in-eclipse-helios) questions, Eclipse should honor environment variables. Set your PYTHONPATH accordingly (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath) or [this answer on how to do it on windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)).

Comment: I actually mean that I want to set it dynamically, which depends on the currently active project. It's not something I can hardcode.

Comment: Short of using virtualenv and launching Eclipse from the command line after you entered the virtual environment I would not know how to do it *easily*.

Answer (score 0):

The `Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations` dialog lets you configure external tools. You can specify environment variables on the `Environment` tab.

Comment: I actually mean that I want to set it dynamically, which depends on the currently active project. It's not something I can hardcode.