# Django Eclipse: How to setup settings module in eclipse (trying to use django shell)?

Tags: python, django, eclipse

So I want to use python shell inside eclipse.

When I click django shell environement in eclipse I get the following prompt: https://i.stack.imgur.com/00yri.jpg

**Now I assume it wants the path to the settings.py file? I so, based on my folder structure (please check the image above!) the path should be `rango.settings.py` right?**

> I've tried that but I get the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'app1'`

What am I doing wrong? please help!

Comment: The dot notation of a Python package or module does not contain the file name suffix (`.py` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the PYTHONPATH variable. For my liking (even though I'm a hardcore eclipse fan), I prefer PyCharm in handling PYTHONPATH.

Make sure your project is set-up correctly ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324502/most-efficient-way-of-setting-up-a-project-pydev-pythonpath-in-eclipse-helios))

[image: Refer to this picture]